# If I want to get the thumbnail URL for a YouTube video, should I be using the "videos" API or the "thumbnails" API?

Tags: video, youtube, youtube-api

The YouTube API has a page for [thumbnails](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/thumbnails) and a page for [videos](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos). If I want the thumbnails for a certain YouTube video, which API should I be using?

I'm inclined to say the thumbnail API, but I can't figure out how to get information out of it? Can I only `set` with it? The first bullet point on the thumbnail API docs seems to indicate that I can get images from it:

> A resource's snippet.thumbnails property is an object that identifies the thumbnail images available for that resource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only method available on `thumbnails` ressource is `set` means :

> Uploads a custom video thumbnail to YouTube and sets it for a video.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/thumbnails

So you can't retrieve a thumbnail of a video with the resource `thumbnails`.
You need to use the ressource `videos.list` https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list with paramter `snippet` and specific videoId